# Nest.js 500 Internal server error при кэшировании

Tags: кэширование, redis, nestjs

При попытке изучить кэширование в Nest.js использую Redis и cahe-manager Postman выкидывает ошибку 500 Internal server error. "cache-manager": "^5.1.6", "cache-manager-redis-store": "^3.0.1".
ссылка на скриншот ошибки в терминале при отправке запроса (https://pastenow.ru/e9d6921c47dd71093458135ada911dc1)
Вот мой код

```
/* App.module.ts */

import { Module, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import * as Joi from 'joi';
import type { ClientOpts } from 'redis';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import configuration from './configuration';

const shcema = Joi.object({
  port: Joi.number().integer().default(3000),
  database: Joi.object({
    host: Joi.string()
      .pattern(/postgres:\/\/[a-zA-Z]/)
      .required(),
    port: Joi.number().integer().required(),
    username: Joi.string(),
    password: Joi.string(),
  }),
});

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: shcema,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useClass: AppService,
    }),
    CacheModule.register<ClientOpts>({
      store: redisStore,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
    }),
    WinstonModule.forRoot({
      levels: {
        critical_error: 0,
        error: 1,
        special_warning: 2,
        another_log_level: 3,
        info: 4,
      },
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({ format: winston.format.simple() }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
      ],
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

/* App.service.ts */

import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';
import { Logger } from 'winston';

@Injectable()
export class AppService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) {}
  createTypeOrmOptions() {
    /* this.logger.log('Creating a user'); */
    return this.configService.get('database');
  }
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello Nest.Js';
  }
}

/* App.controller.ts */

import { Controller, Get, CACHE_MANAGER, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cache: Cache,
  ) {}

  @Get()
  async getHello() {
    const someValue = this.appService.getHello();
    await this.cache.get(someValue);
    if (someValue) {
      return someValue;
    }
    const result = this.appService.getHello();
    await this.cache.set(result, { ttl: 1000 });
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, ошибка была в том что:

1. я не присваивал уникальный ключ для кэширования, оказывается он не смотрит на данные внутри результата функции getHello, а смотрит исключительно на ключ;
2. я сначала вызывал функцию, а потом ее кэшировал, получается что смысл кэширвоания пропадал, так как я каждый раз по новой вызывал функцию
   Вот правильный код:

```
import { Controller, Get, CACHE_MANAGER, Inject, Header } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cache: Cache,
  ) {}

  @Header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, max-age=86400')
  @Get()
  async getHello(): Promise<any> {
    const cacheKey = 'hello1';
    const cachedData = await this.cache.get(cacheKey);
    if (cachedData) {
      return {
        data: cachedData,
        FromRedis: 'this is loaded from redis cache',
      };
    } else {
      const result = this.appService.getHello();
      await this.cache.set(cacheKey, result, 10000);
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```